# IIS 7.5 WebSite reporting "404 - File or directory not found" for Index.html

Tags: iis

IIS 7.5 WebSite reporting "404 - File or directory not found".

Its a simple site located in `"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aaa"` and all that's present is a `"Index.html"`. The physical path is set correctly.

Any Ideas?